# react-query refetchOnWindowFocus in React Native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

I am trying to setup react-query's App Focus Refetch in React Native per: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react-native#refetch-on-app-focus

I have a custom hook which is just a wrapper for the default app focus event listener. However, when leaving and entering the app my queries don't seem to refetch. Do I need to configure anything else? It doesn't say it in the docs.

```js
const [appActive] = useAppState();

useEffect(() => {
  focusManager.setFocused(appActive);
}, [appActive])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using the `useAppState` hook from the [`@react-native-community/hooks`](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks) package, but if you are, the hook doesn't return an array.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/blob/master/src/useAppState.ts#L27), it returns the type of [`AppStateStatus`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L7383).

If that is indeed the case, then you need to set the focused state like this:

```
const state = useAppState();

useEffect(() => {
  focusManager.setFocused(state === 'active');
}, [state])
```

Comment: It’s my own hook which just wraps the `state === ‘active’` and returns a boolean. It does 100% work because I also use it somewhere else.

Comment: Have you set the [`refetchOnWindowFocus: true`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/window-focus-refetching) option on the individual query or in the global options? And also, don't forget about `staleTime`, that is if your query isn't stale it won't refetch on window focus. Do you have `staleTime` configured to be greater than `0`?

Comment: @Kapobajza, how about `refetchOnWindowFocus: always`? I think it will refetch everytime, isn't it?

Comment: @SJaka yeah, you're right. Setting `refetchOnWindowFocus` to `'always'` will refetch regardless if the query is stale or not. Thank you